# Foreach statement to grab a different part of different HTML documents

Tags: php, html

The way I have made the following code is so that it gets the four newest images and HTML documents in a specific folder, and then displays them in order of date posted. Even though it gets the image sorting correct, the overlay system I'm using isn't working correctly.

NEW EDIT for this paragraph: I have fixed most problems except for one. For some reason now, the overlays have decided two trade images, so image 1 displays image 2's overlay, whilst image 2 displays image one's overlay.

If somebody can help, it would be greatly appreciated. I can give an example of the problem at the website I use the code on. [The website, click on the thumbnails in the blue box-ish area](http://tm.tmngp.heliohost.org/).

```
<?php
$i = 1;

$maxiterations = 4;

foreach (glob("news_archive/*.png") as $path)
{
    if($i < $maxiterations)
    {
        $docs[filemtime($path)] = $path;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
asort($docs);
$i2 = 1;

$maxiterations2 = 4;

foreach (glob("news_archive/*.html") as $path2)
{
    if($i2 < $maxiterations2)
    {
        $docs2[filemtime($path2)] = $path2;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }

}
asort($docs2);

$var1;

$var2;

$var3;

$var4;

foreach($docs2 as $timestamp2 => $path2)
{
    if($i2 <= $maxiterations2)
    {
        if($i2 == 1)
        {
            $var1 = $path2;
        }
        elseif($i2 == 2)
        {
            $var2 = $path2;
        }
        elseif($i2 == 3)
        {
            $var3 = $path2;
        }
        elseif($i2 == 4)
        {
            $var4 = $path2;
        }
        $i2 = $i2 + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}



$varcount = 1;
$varcountmax = 4;
foreach($docs as $timestamp => $path)
{
    if($varcount <= $varcountmax)
    {
        if($varcount == 1)
        {
            $prersub=substr($var1, 13, 16);
            $output="<img class='scroll' src='$path' rel='#$prersub' />";
            echo($output);
        }
        if($varcount == 2)
        {
            $prersub=substr($var2, 13, 16);
            $output="<img class='scroll' src='$path' rel='#$prersub' />";
            echo($output);
        }
        if($varcount == 3)
        {
            $prersub=substr($var3, 13, 16);
            $output="<img class='scroll' src='$path' rel='#$prersub' />";
            echo($output);
        }
        if($varcount == 4)
        {
            $prersub=substr($var4, 13, 16);
            $output="<img class='scroll' src='$path' rel='#$prersub' />";
            echo($output);
        }
        $varcount = $varcount + 1;
    }

}




?>
```

Edit: I still have not solved the issue and differences in parts, when corrected, break other parts of the site completely.

Comment: A quick look... are you sure you want the $prersub done on $path2 and not $path? (Hint: I tend to steer clear of vars ending in '2' because its easy to introduce bugs)

Comment: Your line `$prersub=substr($path2, 13, 16);` is the problem, you are using `$path2` which was defined in a previous loop, so it only contains the last one assigned.  Change `$path2` to `$path` and it should work. ^^

Comment: @wittybear I use $path2 because, if I'm correct, $path2 would be basically the path to the html document plus the document. the files name itself is the rel that I need without the '.html' part. Ok, since everyones suggesting to use $path,I'll try it.

Comment: (Note on the question itself: there's probably enough info to go on here, so it's not a bad question. However try to trim down descriptions as much as possible - I removed a good 20% of words by editing. Also, paragraphing! - it makes things _so_ much easier to read. Lastly, try to avoid the phrase "it isn't working" - we have a deep allergy to that phrase here. Much better to say what you expected, and what you got.)

Comment: @Jon I changed $prersub=substr($path2, 13, 16); to $prersub=substr($path, 13, 16); and now overlays don't activate, and the white tab box is now gone.

Comment: Note that if you use $path2 in the final loop its value won't change.

Comment: Also, changing $path2 to $path Does NOT fix the problem. I need to get the changing values from the previous loop for the last loop.

Comment: Then do your `foreach` on `$docs2` rather than `$docs`.  Though, with your loop, it looks like you might be trying to pull data from two variables within it, which the `foreach` isn't really set up for.  Maybe re-index them to `0,1,2,etc` and do a `for` loop and pull from the index the info you need.

Comment: @Jon I ended up doing a major change in the code and used global variables. I now have overlays displaying, but they are switching with each other. I have posted new code.

Comment: I was hoping that I would have gotten a response to this. It seemed like an easy fix, but I can't figure out what's going on that makes it so that the descriptions are with the wrong pictures... They use basically the same exact code, the only difference is the positioning of wait times as well as > and >=, but re positioning them didn't seem to help out any.

Comment: It has been several months... Should I just find a new way to do this?